# PHP socket - Can someone explain me these functions?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a php socket server and I found two functions that mask and unmask a text message (frame).
I think I don't understand clearly how it works.
This is the functions :

```
//encode message for transfer to client
function mask($text)
{ 
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif ($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header . $text;
}

//unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text)
{ 
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }

    return $text;
}
```

What I think I've understood :

mask convert the binary representation of the message and create a frame (by concatenating the header) of the right size according to the message length. (by adding bytes with pack() right?)

unmask -> reverse process.

What I don't understand : 
What is the purpose of this variable $b1 used in mask? The syntax of this code is not clear for me.

```
$b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
```

Comment: The code in question is a [bitmask](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and says 0x80 (=128 in decimal system) or (0x1 and 0x0f). It checks if these bits are set.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jan , it's clearer to me now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is a bit strange to write that way, but here is what is going on. & is a binary AND operator, which takes the two values and returns only the bits that match. 0x1 is 00000001 and 0x0f is 00001111 in binary.

```
 00000001
&00001111
=00000001
```

so (0x1 & 0x0f) is just 0x1 or 1.

The | operator is like &, but is a binary OR. If either side has a 1, the result will be a 1. 0x80 is 01000000, so

```
 01000000
|00000001
=01000001
```

So the total result is 0x81. Why not just write $b1 = 0x81? I'm guessing that the author of this code copied it from some C code where the 0x1 part was a variable:

```
byte b1 = 0x80 | (someVariable & 0x0f);
```

In this case, the binary & with 0x0f ensures that only the last 4 bits of someVariable will be used, and the first 4 bits of b1 will always be 0x8 (which is probably necessary according to the frame specification).

Comment: @Cuagau this is the php port of the original C code segment from one of the Drafts, i believe it was `Hixie-76` but it could have been the 3rd and current version, `Hybi-10`

Comment: @Cuagau , this is very well explained, thank you.
In addition, do you think there is a better method than making a frame at the right size and then unmask it for the client?